# Android: Getting resource id with string

Tags: android, android-resources

I have the string "image.jpg"

image.jpg is in the folder appimages.

appimages is in drawable-mdpi

When I run the following:

```
int res = getResources()
    .getIdentifier("image.jpg",
    "drawable-mdpi/appimages",
    getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

res has a value of 0 (meaning that image.jpg could not be found).

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to put the extension like .jpg, and the folder to look for a drawable, no matter if is in mdpi or hdpi or wathever, is "drawable".

```
int res = getResources().getIdentifier("image", "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Comment: I tried removing the file extension and shortening it to "drawable" but it still isn't working. Not sure if this is relevant but my folder appimages isn't showing up under the drawable folder in project view (although it does show up in Windows file explorer)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just call the image resource id directly if it's in your drawable folder. `R.drawable.image` should work just fine. If it doesn't, moving the image into the root of the drawable folder it's already in should fix the problem.